# Custom Salesforce Header

Tags: apex, home-page-layout, visual

my client has a special requirement. He wants to have a customize header in salesforce. 
[image]

He wants to :
- hidden help&Trainig link
- hidden Setup link
- hidden myprofile link
- insert a custom logout link
- have a different style for the header.

Is it possible ? How can I do that? Thank you for your hints